# Three.js adding a rigged, animated Asset to an existing Scene

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender, gltf

I'm working on a Tamagotchi like browser app in three.js at the moment. But currently I'm stuck with implementing a hand, that pets the avatar when clicked.

The Hand is a rigged Blender model with 2 animations, idle and the poking animation. In the gltf Viewer the model works fine with both animations.
But when added in js, the hand is either completely distorted, or rendered correctly but, positions aren't recognized(for movement with the cursor).

Most of the examples I looked at only added a general scene, but not just one animated model. In both versions of those animations, I get an animation error.

Code for the distorted version:

```
loader.load('resources/models/gltf/Hand.gltf', function(gltf) {
  gltf.scene.traverse(function(node) {
    if (node.isMesh) hand = node;
  });
  //hand.material.morphTargets = true;

  scene.add(hand);
  mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(hand);
  clips = hand.animations;
  hand = gltf;
  scene.add(hand.scene);
});
```

The second version, where the Hand is rendered correctly, but positions for event handling aren't recognized.

```
loader.load('resources/models/gltf/Hand.gltf', function(gltf) {
  var hand = gltf.scene;
  var animations = gltf.animations;
  mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(hand);
  for (var i = 0; i < animations.length; i++) {
    mixer.clipAction(animations[i]).play();
  }
  scene.add(hand);
});
```

function for idle animation:

```
function idleAnim() {
  var idleClip = THREE.AnimationClip.findByName(clips, "Idle");
  var action = mixer.clipAction(idleClip);
  action.play();
  console.log("idling");
}
```

Link: https://github.com/JoeJoe49/AnimTest

Thanks in advance and greetings.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you're pulling the "hand" object out of your import scene, adding it to your render scene, Then adding the rest of the import scene to your render scene.
My guess is that you need to pull out "hand" from higher in the hierarchy. It probably has a few parent objects that need to come along with to preserve the correct hierarchy for the animation.

It's worth doing a scene.traverse((o)=>{console.log(o)} to get a clear picture of how your scene is being exported. I've found with the blender gltf exporter for instance, there are usually 2 separate parent nodes, one for positioning and one for scaling+rotation, so.. it's worth looking at because it might not be exactly what you expect.

fwiw I grabbed your repo and opened the gltfs in my model previewer, but I didn't seem to see any animations on them. My previewer is set to play all animations it finds, in sequence.. so not sure what's going on there. I'm guessing these are skinnedmeshes and not morphtargets?

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. ok, i'll try to dig depper into my model structure then. Unfortunately this is my first project with three.js so I'm experiencing something new every day :D

For the repo, most of the gltf files are animated via shape keys. The Hand model is the only rigged/skinnedmesh. Not sure why your previewer doesn't show the animations. https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/

Comment: If you open the JS console on https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ you'll see a scene tree printout too — in particular, bones are (usually) not children of the mesh in glTF, so if you just extract and append the mesh to your scene, the bones are not in the scene. Easier to append the entire `gltf.scene` object to the scene, then (if that's working) trim things out.

Comment: fwiw I fixed some bugs in my asset previewer, and now I can display all the animation types fine. The hand mesh is animating.. and some morph target animations I pulled from the THREE repo are animating as well.

Comment: I tried to dig a bit deeper into the model structure the alst few days and managed to load the model correctly. @manthrax you were right with the second attempt i posted. The hand model is still rigged to the joints, so if i just load the mesh it get's distorted. the hand is now functional in terms of reacting to an event listener. Animations still won't work as expected, Just getting an error with missing geometry data.

Comment: Not sure if you were asking for more advice.. but.. I think you're not understanding the nature of animations->meshes->geometry relationship.
The mesh hierarchy and animations and geometry all have to be matched up exactly for anything to work. Without a deep understanding of the system, you can't just add/remove/move any of these parts without everything breaking. For animated objects, you need to deal with the highest root of the object in the tree, and not mess interior nodes, until you know what's going on.

Comment: Well, the problem wasn't based on the model structure or anything else. Wasn't even a problem of understanding that nature. It was a simply line that I've forgotten to add. 

 if (hand !== undefined) {....}

My animations were running, before the programm loaded every mesh and with all the details i double and triple checked, I completely didn't think of this problem.

Comment: Yes, it was a missing property error, that mentioned geometry. That was the problem with all this. The programm tried to animate an object, that hadn't been loaded completely.

Comment: Moral of the story is look at the console before stackoverflow ;) Learn to use the debugger. It will save you soooo much time.